# Do uniform convergence functions still uniformly converge after composed by a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$, i.e.
$$
\sup_{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0, \textrm{ as } n \rightarrow\infty.
$$

For a continuous function $g$, can we prove that $g(f_n(x))$ uniformly converges to $g(f(x))$?

If yes, how to prove? If no, what conditions should we add to prove it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If $g$ is merely continuous, then NO. We need to require that $g$ is uniformly continuous. See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If $g$ is merely continous, then the answer is negative. Example: $f_n(x)=x+\frac1n$ uniformly converges to $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb R$, i.e.,
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0,\qquad \text{as }\ \ n\to\infty.$$
Let $g(x)=x^2$, then $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$. We claim that $g\circ f_n$ does not converge to $g\circ f$ uniformly. Indeed,
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|2\frac xn+\frac1{n^2}\right|=\infty,\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb N.$$

If $g$ is uniformly continous, then things will be good!

**Proposition.** If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on a set $D$, and $g:I\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continous, where $I$ is an interval such that $f_n(x),f(x)\in I$ for all $x\in D$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, then $g\circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $g\circ f$ on $D$.

*Proof.* Given $\epsilon>0$, we need to find $N$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in D}|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|<\epsilon, \qquad \forall n>N.$$
By the uniform continuity of $g$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $y_1,y_2\in I$ with $|y_1-y_2|<\delta$ we have
$|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|<\frac\epsilon2.$ Fix such $\delta>0$. Since $\sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$, there exists $N$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta,\qquad \forall n>N.$$
Combining all things together, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have found $N$ such that
$$|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|<\frac\epsilon2,\qquad \forall x\in D, \forall n>N;$$
taking supremum gives that
$$\sup_{x\in D}|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|\leq\frac\epsilon2<\epsilon, \qquad \forall n>N.$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: thank you so much!!!